# What is the difference between "число" and "количество"?

Tags: словоупотребление, лексикон, синонимы

In the newspaper [***Izvestia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izvestia) I have seen the phrase

**число случаев**

and

**количество случаев**

For example:

> [**В мире число случаев заражения коронавирусом превысило 10,3 млн.**](https://iz.ru/1030404/2020-07-01/chislo-vyiavlennykh-sluchaev-koronavirusa-v-mire-prevysilo-103-mln)
>
> *In the world, the number of cases of coronavirus infection has exceeded 10.3 million.*
>
> [**Количество случаев заболевания COVID-19 в Узбекистане превысило 15 тыс**.](https://iz.ru/1036558/2020-07-17/kolichestvo-sluchaev-koronavirusa-v-uzbekistane-prevysilo-15-tysiach)
>
> *The number of COVID-19 cases in Uzbekistan has exceeded 15 thousand.*

I am assuming both of them mean "number of cases," but what, exactly, is the difference between "**число**" and "**количество**" and are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: amount and number

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*количество* means *quantity*, and *число* means *number*.

In the examples you cited they are synonymous, but not in all cases. For example you can say *количество масла* for *amount of butter*. Here, of course число doesn't work. Число only works with countable nouns so far as I have seen.

Comment: And conversely, "quantity" works only for additive things, i.e. it is a result of a summation. "Количество зверя" means "Quantity of wild game", while "Число зверя" means "Number of the beast".

Comment: Great answer.  You can correct me if I'm mistaken, but it seems that if I can swap "quantity" for "number," I can use "количество," otherwise, it would be better to stick to "число."  In other words, "число" can mean both "quantity" and "number" but "количество" only means "number" when it refers to or is synonymous with the meaning of "quantity."

Comment: @LisaBeck You are correct

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference between "число" and "количество" - exept one moment that knows not even russians but only philologist. You cannot say "количество людей" you have to say "число людей". When you say about human, you have to use only "число", but if you say something about fruits, animals, books - you can use both words "число" and "количество". But for the fruits and things better use "количество".

Comment: https://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CA%EE%EB%E8%F7%E5%F1%F2%E2%EE+%EB%FE%E4%E5%E9

Comment: https://search1.ruscorpora.ru/stat.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CA%EE%EB%E8%F7%E5%F1%F2%E2%EE%20%EB%FE%E4%E5%E9

Comment: Doesn't число яблок work okay?